# android : prevent column from stretching in gridview

Tags: android

am trying out a simple gridview, where in the number of elements come from an Adapter dynamically. Here is a screenshot where you can see two children added:

[image]

**ISSUE**
The children are getting stretched along the width (I have intentionally given the blue background for the child's layout to make the stretch obvious). 
I have given a specific width and height for the child. I don't understand why it is getting stretched. I tried many options in GridView element like 'stretchMode' parameters, 'clipChildren', all in vain.

Here is the parent layout (which has the top bar and the gridview)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <!-- relativelayout of topbar -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_topbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayoutTopBar"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dip"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the layout for each child in the gridview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="252dp"
android:layout_height="302dp"
android:background="#3421de" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_name"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="55dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_save_plan_name"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:textColor="#2b911e"
        android:textSize="14sp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="63dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_img_delete"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="DELETE"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="11dp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_start"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="BEGIN"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="11dp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_end"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_start"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="END"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="11dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/common_btn_green_pressed" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

can someone please help?

Comment: specify android:columnWidth="100dp" for GridView

Comment: no, that doesn't work @GopalRao