# Preventing columns from stretching in a gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a grid view in which it has 2 columns as this:

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/therapy_grid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

it stretches as fill all the width but I want it to prevent from stretching. I read  this topic too: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921829/android-prevent-column-from-stretching-in-gridview), but cant find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CustomImageView.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class CustomImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        try {
            getLayoutParams().height = getMeasuredWidth();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //no-op
        }
    }
}
```

**xml using:**

```
<com.example.myapplication.CustomImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For stop stretching change stretchMode in your xml like this:

```
android:stretchMode="none"
```

or use one of the following modes:

`columnWidth`: Each column is stretched equally.

`none`: Stretching is disabled.

`spacingWidth`: The spacing between each column is stretched.

`spacingWidthUniform`: The spacing between each column is uniformly stretched..

you can find more details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:stretchMode)

Comment: can you attach screenshot to your post for better understanding the problem?